# Populate Cell Range Based on User Selection

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

There will be one cell (B2) that will allow a user to input a day of the week. Based on the day selected, there will be a range of cells (C2:F4) that would be populated with corresponding text/color/formatting. I can use a formula to pull in text based on the result, but am struggling how to also populate formatting (cell fill color, etc...).

For example, if Sunday is selected then C2:F4 should contain the contents of H2:K4.

I've included a screenshot illustrating this example:

[image]

Comment: "contents of H2:K4" : Does this mean the color only, or also the nonsense text?

Comment: I imagine you're limited to 7 conditional format rules all based on the value in `B2` and applying to the range `C2:F4` or a VBA solution that copies/pastes cells whenever `B2` changes. The only other option I can think if is to use the camera tool and change it's formula to be based on the value in `B2` but that's messy and you get a shape object, not cells. It would *look* close to right but wouldn't be.

Comment: @harrymc - You're correct. The nonsense text, the cell color and font color would all need to be pulled in. I just entered placeholder text for the screenshot.

Comment: @EngineerToast - What if I added 7 images within the sheet? I wonder if I could choose to display Image 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, etc... so that it doesn't need to capture the formatting attributes since the image would have those included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write the trigger in VBA.
The spreadsheet file will need to have the extension `.xlsm` rather than
`.xls`.

I suggest to convert the options list to a drop-down list. See Microsoft's
[Create and manage drop-down lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-create-and-manage-drop-down-lists-28db87b6-725f-49d7-9b29-ab4bc56cefc2).

Then you can trap a change in the drop-down list by a VBA trigger such as:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
      If Target.Value = "SUNDAY" Then
         Cells(1, 2) = "abc"
         ...
      ElseIf Target.Value = "MONDAY" Then
         Cells(1, 2) = "xyz"
         ...
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

The above code was just an untested example.
You will need to learn VBA in order to complete it,
but you will easily find all you need on the internet.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc! I will give this a shot. A little rusty on my VBA but it's a good time to dust off those skills. Appreciate the help!

Comment: If you have all the data stored somewhere else in the file, then you can copy / paste everything in one line: `Sheet1.Range("H2:K4").Copy Sheet1.Range("C2:F4")`

Answer (score 0):

You can make something that *looks* right without VBA but it's a little messy. If you have users that are sensitive to allowing macros to run, though, this is a workaround. Starting with your data setup how it is, follow these steps:

1. Create a blank section. It would fit nicely next to Saturday.
2. Use the [camera tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamically-display-the-contents-of-a-cell-or-range-in-a-graphic-object-e2e7a629-5662-42d6-9295-06d112c2099f) to take a snapshot of one of your sections and move it into place in the results section. You can format it like any other shape so you can turn off its borders to make it look more correct.
   [image: Step2]
3. Somewhere else, create a formula that returns the range *address* you want to display for the various Options. I haven't filled out all the options in this example, but you can add the others. The `0` at the end is in case Option is blank.
   `=SWITCH(B2,"SUNDAY","H2:K4","MONDAY","L2:O4",0,"L14:O16")`
4. From the Formulas ribbon, open the Name Manager. Click "New" in the top left and create a named range that points to wherever that `SWITCH()` formula is but wrap it inside an `INDIRECT()` function. In my case, the formula was in `B7` so it looked like this:
   [image: NameManager]
5. Change the formula within your camera tool shape to point to the named range you just created. You can select the shape and then just edit the formula directly in the formula bar.
   [image: FormulaInShape]
6. Change the Option and be amazed at what Excel can (kind of) do.
   [image: Monday]